# SELECT COUNT DISTINCT QUESTION (snowflake sql)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Would like the SQL experts to chime in on what the difference between  A and B is?

A) two different "SELECT COUNT DISTINCT" queries giving different number of count distinct on same table

```
-- query 1  select count with "distinct subquery" 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM TABLE_A);    -- RETURNS 11000

-- query 2  select count with "distinct CONCAT subquery" 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) FROM TABLE_A);   -- RETURNS 5699
```

B) reworking the two queries now using  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ...)  and they provide THE SAME count

```
-- query 1  using "COUNT(distinct ...)" 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)  FROM TABLE_A;    -- RETURNS 5699

-- query 2  using "COUNT(distinct CONCAT ...)" 


SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) FROM TABLE_A;   -- RETURNS 5699
```

Comment: Does your data have a lot of NULL values in these columns?  That would explain the difference in count between query 1a and 1b.  However, I'm then a bit surprised by the result of query 1b.

Comment: Use `explain` to see how the query executed.  It should give you an idea of the index used for each one

Comment: @Mako212 I don't think that is the case.

Comment: @MikeWalton yes there are null values  in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all about NULLs:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A(col1 INT, col2 INT)
AS
SELECT *
FROM VALUES (1,2),(1,2),(1,NULL),(1, NULL),(NULL,2);


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE_A);  
-- 3

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(COL1, COL2) FROM TABLE_A); 
-- 2


SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COL1, COL2)  FROM TABLE_A;
-- 1

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(COL1, COL2)) FROM TABLE_A;
-- 1
```

---

[Aggregate Functions and NULL Values](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-aggregation#aggregate-functions-and-null-values):

> Some aggregate functions can be passed more than one column. For example:
>
> SELECT COUNT(col1, col2) FROM table1;
>
> **In these instances, the aggregate function ignores a row if any individual column is NULL.**

---

`CONCAT` function returns NULL if any of the columns in NULL. One way to count NULLs is to use `ARRAY` - `ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(col1, col2)` or `[col1, col2]`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE_A);  
-- 3

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [COL1, COL2]) FROM TABLE_A;
-- 3
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that the `SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT CONCAT(.....)))`  statement already excluddes the count for null values it seems.     

Whereas when doing the  subquery ` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4... ` statement I would have to add the WHERE condition  `WHERE COL1 IS NOT NULL AND COL2 IS NOT NULL....`    to make it not include the null counts.